# Hartshorne II.6.2d)m Varieties in Projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X$ be a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ which is nonsingular in codimension $1.$ Suppose that we have a principal divisor $D$ on $X.$ I want to show that there is a rational function $f$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ so that $D = (f) \cap X$ (i.e the restriction of the divisor defined by $f$ to $X$). I think I can see a very easy solution, but I'm a bit unsure if my reasoning is correct. Hopefully you can help me.

Let $D$ be the principal divisor above, defined by $g \in K(X).$ Take some open affine $U \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ such that $g$ is a regular function on $X \cap U.$ We then know that the map $U\cap X \rightarrow U$ is a closed immersion as well, so it is surjective on sections. Thus we can find some $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ such that the image of $f$ under this closed immersion is precisely $g.$ The divisor of $(f)$is clearly the same as that of $D,$so we're done.

Does this seem OK or am I wrong?

Comment: Why is it obvious that $div(f) = D$? I like the argument, but it seems that you are asserting the existence of a rational function whose restriction to some dense open subset agrees with $D$ on that dense open subset. How do you know that when you extend $f$ to $X$ it agrees with $D$?

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to consider the epimorphism of local rings $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}=K(X)$, where $\eta$ is the generic point of $X$. The $f$ is exactly a preimage of $g$.

We have proved in (b) that $(f){.}X=\sum_{Y} v_{_Y}(g')\cdot Y=(g')_{_X}$, where $g'$ is the image of $f$ under the homomorphism mapping into the $K(X)^*$, from a subgroup of $K(\mathbb{P}^n_k)^*$ consisting of the functions, whose principal divisor has no component containing $X$. In particular, the functions of the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}$, not in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}$, is just of this type. And such homomorphism, when restricted to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}\backslash\mathfrak{m}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}$, just conincides with the ring morphism $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k,\eta}\twoheadrightarrow K(X)$ above. Thus $g=g'$.